# SetInternet2 Proxy Behavoir with RCurl Package

Tags: r, proxy, rcurl

I am working on a project web scraping where I want to use RCurl with the SetInternet2 proxy settings.  My understanding based on research is that RCurl uses its own proxy.

As the proxy settings are controlled by the network admin, I do not currently have the Proxy settings.

I found a relevant post here http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/SetInternet2-RCurl-and-proxy-td3248576.html, however that community is not what it used to be.

So my question is, is there a way to use RCurl with SetInternet2? Are there any alternative libraries/codes I can use that will allow me to scrape? If not, is there a way to store the proxy settings from setInternet2 into a variable and define it as part of the RCurl settings?

Comment: No, RCurl and `setInternet2()` are completely independent. You will need to manually determine your proxy settings and replicate them with the appropriate Curl settings.

Comment: Thanks Hadley! Is there any code to pull that proxy information back?

Comment: I don't think so - `setInternet2()` just tells R to use Window's built-in internet stuff which already knows about your proxy.